# PHP my sql textbox value comparision with database field value

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, connectivity

My objective is to compare oldwifi name,oldwifipassword with inputbox1 and input box2.I want to allow user to change wifi name and password only after confirming old wifiname and password.

Below is my code.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
$oldwifi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['oldwifi']);
$oldpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['oldpass']);
$sql="UPDATE test SET dboldwifi = '".$oldwifi."',dboldpass = '".$oldpass."'WHERE id = '1'";
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
else if(mysql_query($sql)&&strcmp($oldwifi,'dboldwifi')==0&&strcmp($oldpass,'dboldpass')==0)
  {
        echo "New wifi and password saved successfully !";
  }
else
{
        echo "Old credentials mismatch";
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My database :

```
mysql> select * from test;
+-----------+-----------+----+
| dboldwifi | dboldpass | id |
+-----------+-----------+----+
| Tarzan    | Jane      |  1 |
+-----------+-----------+----+
```

HTML Code

```
<html>

<body>

<h1>A small example page to insert some data in to the MySQL database using PHP</h1>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">

Firstname: <input type="text" name="oldwifi" /><br><br>

Lastname: <input type="text" name="oldpass" /><br><br>



<input type="submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Output Result : Old credentials mismatchError:

I am beginner in php mysql need help where i am doing wrong !

below is working Code when i try to insert data;

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO test (dboldwifi, dboldpass)VALUES ('$_POST[oldwifi]','$_POST[oldpass]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you !

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Given how the labels here are firstname/lastname and I can only presume you're adapting some sort of existing script, **DO NOT** use this code as a base. It's ancient and full of potential hazards.

Comment: thanks for the response tadman ! yes i am following some existing scripts as i told you i am beginner. I will try to learn PDO but for now please ignore lables and let me know if there is any solution for my question.

Comment: If you want to verify the old password before inserting you'll need to fetch that with a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is very bad and you're getting the order of operations wrong. Try to clean up your code and it will make it easier to debug.

`elseif(mysql_query($sql)&&strcmp($oldwifi,'dboldwifi')==0&&strcmp($oldpass,'dboldpass')==0)`

This is literally saying:

```
if (updateTheRow && noDifferenceWifi && noDifferentPwd)
```

What you want it to say is:

```
if (noDifferenceWifi && noDifferentPwd) {
    updateTheRow
```

Also, you're comparing what the user entered to the literal string 'dboldwifi'.

Try this:

```
<?php
// Set up your connection here. You can also put this in a config file
// but the whole point is to get access to the $pdo variable. 
// See line 17
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

// Don't need to escape because PDO is awesome
$oldwifi = $_POST['oldwifi'];
$oldpass = $_POST['oldpass'];

// Now use that $pdo variable in your application to query, update, delete etc.
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE dboldwifi=? AND dboldpass=?');
$stmt->execute([$oldwifi, $oldpass]);
$match = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ($match) {
    // Now update your row here using PDO. 
    // https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dml
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Mr waterloomatt. let me give a try on your code. it gave me a clear picture now but again PDO is new for me..Anyway thanks